# Does "Our goal in creating this series was twofold" mean "Our goal when creating this series was twofold"?

Tags: prepositions

Does "Our goal in creating this series was twofold" mean "Our goal when creating this series was  twofold" ?

What is the exact difference in the meaning between "Our goal in creating this series was twofold" and "Our goal creating this series was twofold" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Our goal **in** creating this series was twofold. We wanted to emphasize issues related to woman's rights.

This refers to the overall reasons for creating the series, and what you wanted to accomplish.

> Our goal **when** creating this series was twofold. We wanted to hire a famous producer and scriptwriter.

This refers to specific thinking or activity at the time you were creating the series.

You can leave out *in* or *when* saying it is implied, but the meaning could be misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

Small correction: *Does* not *dose*.

---

I think

> Our goal when creating this series was twofold.

is a very good interpretation. It really depends on the overall context, but this one seems pretty good to me, as it stands.

The difference between

1. "Our goal in creating this series was twofold" and
2. "Our goal creating this series was twofold"

seems minor. 2. seems more causal or informal than 1. Sentence 2. is a grammatically incorrect version of sentence 1. since I believe there should be a preposition before the word *creating*. However, it still sounds natural and clear to me. I can easily imagine a native speaker saying or writing this, and it is understandable.